# mysql procedure - random number from five numbers

Tags: mysql, random

I have 5 INT variables with numbers. I want select one random number from five variables in mysql procedure.

Example data:

```
DECLARE a, b, c, d, e INT;
SET a = 50;
SET B = 22;
SET C = 88;
SET D = 892;
SET E = 367;
```

Now I want to select one random number from variables a, b, c, d, e. Any ideas how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

UPDATE

> SELECT * FROM
>
> (
>
> SELECT @A AS Val
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT @B AS Val
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT @C AS Val
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT @D AS Val
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT @E AS Val
>
> ) F
>
> ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1